# Nuxt: how to fetch subdirectories (names only) using $content

Tags: nuxt.js

Is there a way to `fetch` the subdirectories in Nuxt?

For example if I have a content structure as follows:

```
content
   course-c1
      subj-c1s1
         content.md
      subj-c1s2
         content.md
      ...
   course-c2
      subj-c2s1
         content.md
      subj-c2s2
         content.md
      ...
   ....
```

I would like to:

1. fetch all the courses generating an array ['course-c1', 'course-c2'] and another
2. fetch all subjects of course `course-c1` which should generate ['subj-c1s1', 'subj-c1s2']

Thanks